# Jquery: button click to show an overlay with an id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple buttons and overlays.  On click of a button, I want it to show a specific overlay attached to each button.

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(".overlay:visible").hide();
  $("#" + $(this).attr("data-showdiv")).show();
})
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="button" id="button1" href="#" data-showdiv="overlay1">Click here for more Information</button>
</div>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay1">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <img src="" alt="topic image">
  <p>Topic text 1</p>
  <p class="cross">X</p>
</div>
```

How can I get this to function to show the correct overlay for each button?

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet where it appears to work fine. Can you give some more details about what the exact problem is.

Comment: It also works fine with multiple buttons and divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope will help you
[demo for you](https://codepen.io/thamtucity/pen/ajRRVP)

css:

```
.overlay {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <button class="button" id="button1" href="#" data-showdiv="overlay1">Click here for more Information</button>
   <button class="button" id="button2" href="#" data-showdiv="overlay2">Click here for more Information</button>
    <button class="button" id="button3" href="#" data-showdiv="overlay3">Click here for more Information</button>
</div>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay1">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <img src="" alt="topic image">
  <p>Topic text 1</p>
  <p class="cross">X</p>
</div>
<div class="overlay" id="overlay2">
  <h1>Title2</h1>
  <img src="" alt="topic image">
  <p>Topic text 2</p>
  <p class="cross">X2</p>
</div>
<div class="overlay" id="overlay3">
  <h1>Title3</h1>
  <img src="" alt="topic image">
  <p>Topic text 3</p>
  <p class="cross">X3</p>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(".overlay:visible").hide();
  $("#" + $(this).attr("data-showdiv")).show();
})
```

Please respond if you do not agree :)

Comment: Thank you.  This works.  I must have an issue on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button").on('click', function(e){
    var elId = $(this).data('showdiv'); // Get data attribute
    $(".overlay").hide(); // Hide all overlays
    $("#"+elId).show(); // Better add # direct to data attribute for element, so here we can remove this, btw.: data-showdiv="#overlay1", js: $(elId).show();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: kindly add some description about your approach so that anyone looking at your answer can understand in the first glance.

Answer (score 0):

This how to solve your issue. You almost there but need to do some tweaking.

**HTML**

```
 <button class="button" id="button1" href="#" data-showdiv="overlay1">Click here for more Information</button>    
 </div>

 <div class="overlay" id="overlay1">
     <h1>Title</h1>
     <img src="" alt="topic image">
     <p>Topic text 1</p>
     <p class="cross">X</p>
</div>

<br/><br/>

 <button class="button" id="button2" href="#" data-showdiv="overlay1">Click here for more Information</button>    
 </div>

 <div class="overlay" id="overlay1">
     <h1>Title</h1>
     <img src="" alt="topic image">
     <p>Topic text 1</p>
     <p class="cross">X</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".button").click(function() {
 $(this).next('.overlay').show();
})
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay {
  display: none;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gv4y35qz/)

Let me know if this solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data attribute that is set

```js
$(".button").on('click', function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("data-showdiv");
      $("#overlay_"+id).show(); 
      //console.log(id); testing to see if the id is correct
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="button" id="button_1" href="#" data-showdiv="1">Click here for more Information</button>
</div>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay_1">
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <img src="" alt="topic image">
  <p>Topic text 1</p>
  <p class="cross">X</p>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="button" id="button_2" href="#" data-showdiv="2">Click here for more Information</button>
</div>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay_2">
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <img src="" alt="topic image">
  <p>Topic text 2</p>
  <p class="cross">X</p>
</div>
```